# jEditable, undefined settings when using callback function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jeditable

I'm using jEditable and instead of using ajax to save, I just want to use the callback function to put the contents into a hidden form elements, the problem is using the callback function I receive this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

This is the code I'm using:

```
     $('.editable').editable(function(value, settings) { 
         console.log(this);
         console.log(value);
         console.log(settings);
         return(value);
      }, { 
         submit  : 'OK'
     });
```

Any ideas what the problem could be? Thank you!

Comment: Could it be somewhere else in the code? What versions of jQuery and jEditable are you using? It seems to work at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/william/6VUHh/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had simillar problem with dblckick event.

Jquery.validate plugin (v 1.7) was throwing this error.

Fixed by installing new version of [Jquery.validate (v 1.9).](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error message. But in that case I used the plugin **ajaxupload** for jEditable in my Javascript and called it like that:

```
$("edit_photo").editable{type:"ajaxupload"};
```

On updating jQuery I made only one file containing all the minified stuff to reduce the web to a single request. Then I recognized, that the plugin **ajaxupload** just was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I was making a call to `$("#element").rules()` before a call to `$("#form").validate()` on the form DOM element. There error was the same using both jQuery Validate version 1.7 and 1.9 (I upgraded per the above suggestion before getting it to work).